# VB.Net SQLClient. Best practice for connections in threads

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a DLL which reads from and writes to an SQL Server database. The calling module currently sets up the connection to the database prior to calling the DLL.

The module calls the DLL on different threads, so it's possible to have 30-40 threads running at the same time which have all called the public method of the DLL.

The question is, for SQL Server, is it better for all threads to use the same connection, i.e. the one that is passed from the main module, or should each one establish it's own connection?

I've currently got it using the common connection but I keep getting errors from some threads saying "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." despite having all my readers in a monitor.enter/exit block so the reader is finsihed with before the monitor.exit(obj) is reached.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question.  Some things you do on one thread is going to prevent any other thread from using the same connection for anything

Comment: *Don't* use a common connection. There is a reason all samples and tutorials have a `using` statement to close the connection as soon as possible. Closing a connection releases all locks and resources used on the server. Connection pooling means that you don't have to pay a reconnection penalty the next time you open a connection.

Comment: I agree with the others that funneling everything through a single connection will cause issues. Why do you want to do this vs. connection pooling and letting each thread grab a connection from the pool as needed?

Comment: Thanks peeps. I'm new to working with threads to be honest. I'll re-work with the advised methods and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the advice. Passing a connection string and allowing the threads to create their own connection seems to have solved the issue. The "DataReader" problem was caused by me creating a reader on a connection and then neglating to use it... Hey ho...